# cannot execute program without using sudo

Tags: php, c, linux, raspberry-pi

I am having trouble getting a file to execute without typing `sudo` before it. I think the problem is the libraries I used require you to be a superuser.

I am working on a program for the `Raspberry Pi` and so far everything has worked great. The program takes a command line argument and outputs it to a separate 2x16 LCD. So if I type the following command as root or place `sudo` in front of it the program functions as intended:`./serialTest Hello World`.

What I am working on now is getting the value of a text box on a `PHP` webpage and submitting it to the program as a command line argument using the `exec()` function in `PHP` The problem is that I am unable to execute it because unless I am `root` I have tried `exec("sudo ./serialTest" . $textBox);` but it still tells me `Permission Denied`

After further reading into the libraries I am using I cam across instructions on how to execute the `serialOpen` function without using `sudo` or being `root` I have added the user `pi` and `www-data` to the `dialout` group I have verified this with `id pi` `id www-data`. The program still says `Permission denied`. Is there something I could look at further or am I doing something wrong? I have included the excerpt from the page that states how to run it without using `sudo` or being `root`

```
You can use it without sudo if you add yourself into the dialout group. either edit /etc/group, or use the usermod command. (and logout/login again)
-Gordon
```

Comment: did you restart Apache after making the group changes?

Comment: Yes I restarted the Pi

Comment: ten I suggest using `strace` to get a capture of what's happening in the background. e.g. `exec('strace ./serialtest')`. strace will output the syscall stack for everything the app is doing. at some point you'll see where the permission denied is coming from.

Comment: this is what it says `open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "Unable to open serial device: Pe"..., 48Unable to open serial device: Permission denied
) = 48
`

Comment: what's the ownership on that tty, then? if its gid isn't dialout, then the permissions changes you'd done earlier were useless.

Comment: `crw-rw---- 1 root tty     204,  64 Feb 28 20:45 ttyAMA0`

Comment: ok. so you user IDs need to be in the tty group.

Comment: I am now getting this `write(2, "wiringPi:\n  Must be root to call"..., 75wiringPi:
  Must be root to call wiringPiSetup().
  (Did you forget sudo?)
) = 75`

Comment: I suggest you read up on how wiringPi works, from what I understand from a quick look the default mode requires root rights due to raw hardware IO. There is another alternative mode but how that is used I leave as exercise to the poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the server rights provided by Server Service Provider. If you are the Service Prover then edit the Shell Access Rights to executed Exec command in PHP configuration file. As default, exec is not provided in default that's why the message is coming

If you are not service provider then contact them to do things..